# Get data from pressed picture and save them and send as email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website project. I used to work in asp.net so I am very familiar with it. However, this project is in php ...

I have searched a lot and did not find a way in which php can send data from an image (asp.net could do that).

My question is the following how can I get data from the picture that was pressed and save all these data to send them then as an email to the owner of the website.

The scenario is the following:

The thing is that I have a form (that is on sliding divs) composed of pictures.
The slides move left and right using jquery (and their display is set to none)
For example:
Slide 1 have three pictures (decorate your table and plan your event)

CASE 1 : if you press on Plan your event you go to Slide 2 , here we need to save "Plan event"
Slide 2 have three other pictures (Birthday event, Baby Shower , Wedding)
if you press on one of these you will be taken to the next slide (relevant to it) and we have to save "Birthday Event" for example and so on

CASE 2 : if you press on decorate your table you go to Slide 3 , here we need to save "decorate your table"
Slide 4 has two other pictures (open buffet, Canape)
if you press on one of these you will be taken to the next slide (relevant to it) and we have to save "Canape" for example and so on

At the end of this form , there is a send button that needs to gather all the previously saved data and send it as an email to the owner of the website.

For example in the first sceneraio the email would look something like this:
You received an order.
Order: Event Planning
Type: Birthday

In the second scenario the email would look something like this:
You received an order.
Order: Table Decoration
Type: Canape

and so on.

The html code of the slides

```
    <div id="Plan">


<div id="SubPlan">


<div id="Plan0">
<table id="PlanTable">
<tr>
<td><h1>START <br /> PLANNING <br/> NOW</h1></td>
<td><img id="PlanEvent" src="Pictures/plan/plan-your-event.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></td>
<td><img id="PlanEventTable" src="Pictures/plan/customize-your-display-table.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></td>
<td><img id="CustomizeCake" src="Pictures/plan/customize-your-cake.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>




<!--Plan Event Section-->


<!--1-->
<div id="Occasion" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>PLAN YOUR EVENT</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT IS YOUR OCCASION?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_01.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_02.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_03.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div  class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_04.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_05.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_06.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_07.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="Occasionbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_08.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left Occasionbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right Occasionbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>




<!--2-->
<div id="DecorationType" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>PLAN YOUR EVENT</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT ARE WE DECORATING?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class=" col-xtra-12"><img style="max-width: 300px; margin-bottom:20px;" class="DecorationType " src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_main.png" /></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img class="DecorationTypebtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_1.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img class="DecorationTypebtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_2.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737c"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="DecorationTypebtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_3.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#f4d7cb"></div></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left DecorationTypebtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right DecorationTypebtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>




<!--3-->
<div id="Catering"  >
<div class="PlanWrapper" >
<div class="row PlanTitle"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>PLAN YOUR EVENT</h1></div></div>
<div class="row PlanOption"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>CATERING?</p></div></div>


<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-1 PlanRemove "></div>
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn1  animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Catering_1.png" /> <div class="ButtonBackground"></div>  </div> 
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-3"><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn1 animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Catering_2.png" />  <div class="ButtonBackground"></div> </div>
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-3"><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn1 animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Catering_3.png" />  <div class="ButtonBackground"></div> </div>
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-1 PlanRemove "></div>
</div>

<div class="row PlanOption"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>HOW MANY PEOPLE ARE WE CATERING TO?</p></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn2 animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_1.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737c"></div> </div>
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn2 animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_2.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737c"></div> </div>
<div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn2 animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_3.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737c"></div> </div>
<div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Cateringbtn Cateringbtn2 animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_4.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737c"></div> </div>

</div>

<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left Cateringbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right Cateringbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>

</div>
</div>


<!--4-->
<div id="TableColor" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>PLAN YOUR EVENT</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT IS YOUR TABLE COLOR?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="TableColorbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_1.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="TableColorbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_2.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="TableColorbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_3.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="TableColorbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_4.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-12 col-xs-3"><p class="decootherstyle" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;" >OTHER</p> </div> <div class="col-xtra-12 col-xs-9"> <input class="inputstyle3" />  </div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left TableColorbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right TableColorbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--</div>-->


<!--5-->
<div id="Decoration">
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row PlanTitle"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>PLAN YOUR EVENT</div></div>
<div class="row PlanOption"><div class="col-xtra-12"><p>DECORATION</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_1.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> <div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_2.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_3.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_4.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis"src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_5.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> <div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_6.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> <div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_7.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="Decorationbtn animatethis" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_8.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"><div  class=" col-xs-3 PlanRemove "></div><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "> <img class="Decorationbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_9.png"/> <div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div> </div><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><p class="decootherstyle" >OTHER</p> <textarea name="DecorationOther" class="inputstyle"></textarea> </div><div  class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 PlanRemove"></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left Decorationbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right Decorationbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>



<!--6-->
<div id="Entertainment">
<div>
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>PLAN YOUR EVENT</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>ENTERTAINMENT</p></div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-5"> 
<textarea name="DecorationOther" placeholder="WHAT IS THE OCCASION?"></textarea>
<textarea name="DecorationOther" placeholder="HOW MANY PERSONS ARE YOU INVITING?"></textarea>
 <textarea name="DecorationOther" placeholder="SWEET CANAPE OR SAVORY CANAPE OR BOTH?"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5"> <div class="EntArea"> <h5>THEMED SWEETS? YES OR NO</h5> <textarea name="DecorationOther" placeholder="(CUPCAKES, COOKIES, CAKE POPS, MINI CUPCAKES...)"></textarea> <div style="width:100%;"><p style="margin-right:5px; color:white">YES</p><p style="color: white;">NO</p></div> </div>   </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 nextbtn" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span> </div>
</div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left Entertainmentbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right Entertainmentbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--Plan Event Section-->
















<!--Cake Section-->

<!--1-->
<div id="PlanCake" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR CAKE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT IS YOUR EVENT?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_01.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_02.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_03.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div  class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_04.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-1_2 PlanRemove " ></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_05.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_06.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanCakebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_07.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-1_2 PlanRemove"></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left PlanCakebtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right PlanCakebtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--2-->
<div id="CakeSize">
<div class="PlanWrapper three">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR CAKE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT IS THE SIZE NEEDED?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="CakeSizebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake-size_1.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake-size_2.png" class="CakeSizebtn" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake-size_3.png" class="CakeSizebtn"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div>
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-2 PlanRemove " ></div><div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img class="CakeSizebtn"src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake-size_4.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><p class="decootherstyle" >OTHER</p> <textarea name="DecorationOther" class="inputstyle"></textarea> </div><div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-2 PlanRemove" ></div></div>

<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left CakeSizebtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right CakeSizebtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!--Cake Section-->




<!--Table Section-->

<!--1-->
<div id="PlanTableOccasion" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR DISPLAY TABLE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT IS YOUR OCCASION?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_01.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_02.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_03.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div  class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_04.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_05.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_06.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_07.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanTableOccasionbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Customize-your-cake_08.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left PlanTableOccasionbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right PlanTableOccasionbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>

</div>
</div>



<!--2-->
<div id="PlanTableDecorationType" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR DISPLAY TABLE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT ARE WE DECORATING?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class=" col-xtra-12"><img style="max-width: 300px; margin-bottom:20px;" class="PlanCakeBtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_main.png" /></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img class="PlanTableDecorationTypebtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_1.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img class="PlanTableDecorationTypebtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_2.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737c"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanTableDecorationTypebtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-are-we-decorating_3.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#f4d7cb"></div></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left PlanTableDecorationTypebtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right PlanTableDecorationTypebtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--3-->
<div id="PlanEventDecoration">
<div class="PlanWrapper three">
<div  class="row PlanTitle"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR DISPLAY TABLE</h1></div></div>
<div><div class="CateringPadding"><p>DECORATION</p></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventDecorationbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_10.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"  style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div> 
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventDecorationbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_11.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"  style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div>
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img  class="PlanEventDecorationbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_12.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"  style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div>
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "> <img class="PlanEventDecorationbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_13.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"  style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div>
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventDecorationbtn" src="Pictures/plan/Decoration_14.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"  style="background-color: #f4d7cb;"></div></div>
<div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><p class="decootherstyle" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;" >OTHER</p> <textarea name="DecorationOther" class="inputstyle"></textarea> </div></div>

<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left PlanEventDecorationbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right PlanEventDecorationbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>

</div>

</div>


<!--4-->
<div id="PlanTableColor" >
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR DISPLAY TABLE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>WHAT IS YOUR TABLE COLOR?</p></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanTableColorbtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_1.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 " ><img class="PlanTableColorbtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_2.png"/><div class="ButtonBackground" style=" background: silver; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #cbcdce, #a9abae ,#cbcdce , #a7a9ac); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cbcdce, #a9abae, #cbcdce , #a7a9ac); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cbcdce, #a9abae, #cbcdce , #a7a9ac); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #cbcdce, #a9abae , #cbcdce , #a7a9ac); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableColorbtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_3.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div> <div class=" col-xtra-6 col-xs-3 "><img class="PlanTableColorbtn" src="Pictures/plan/what-is-your-table-color_4.png" /><div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div></div>
<div class="row"> <div class=" col-xtra-12 col-xs-3"><p class="decootherstyle" style="background-color: #f4d7cb;" >OTHER</p> </div> <div class="col-xtra-12 col-xs-9"> <input class="inputstyle3" />  </div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left PlanTableColorbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right PlanTableColorbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>



<!--5-->
<div id="PlanEventCatering" style="left: 0px; right:0px ; margin:0 auto">
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row PlanTitle"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR DISPLAY TABLE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row PlanOption"><div class="col-xtra-12"><p>CATERING?</p></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventCateringBtnTypebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Catering_4.png"  /> <div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div>
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 " ><img class="PlanEventCateringBtnTypebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Catering_5.png" /> <div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div>
<div class="CateringPadding col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img  class="PlanEventCateringBtnTypebtn" src="Pictures/plan/Catering_6.png" /> <div class="ButtonBackground"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row PlanOption"><div class="col-xtra-12"><p>HOW MANY PEOPLE ARE WE CATERING TO?</p></div></div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventCateringBtnNbbtn" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_1.png"/> <div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737C"></div></div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventCateringBtnNbbtn" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_2.png"/> <div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737C"></div></div>
<div class="col-xtra-6 col-xs-4 "><img class="PlanEventCateringBtnNbbtn" src="Pictures/plan/NbCatering_3.png" /> <div class="ButtonBackground" style="background-color:#91737C"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="row AddMargin">
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left PlanEventCateringbtn_prev" ></span>  </div> 
<div class="col-xtra-6" style="text-align:right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right PlanEventCateringbtn_next"></span> </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--Table Section-->



<!--Shared Final Section-->
<div id="FinalStep">
<div>
<div class="PlanWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12"><h1>CUSTOMIZE YOUR DISPLAY TABLE</h1></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" ><p>FINAL STEP</p></div></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6"> 
<input name="DecorationOther" placeholder="WHAT IS THE DATE?" /> 
<input name="DecorationOther" placeholder="NAME"/>
 <input name="DecorationOther" placeholder="LOCATION"/>
 <input name="DecorationOther" placeholder="E-MAIL"/> 
  <input name="DecorationOther" placeholder="TELEPHONE"/> </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6"> <textarea name="DecorationOther"  placeholder="NOTES AND MESSAGES"></textarea>  </div>
</div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xtra-12" style="text-align:right"><p>SEND</p></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of describing the logic and markup you are working with currently that you are having an issue with, please *show* that logic and markup.

Comment: the markup and logic is very long , i simplified the problem in 4 slides , in fact there is like 20 slides in total , so it would be very confusing for people to read all of it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out , i updated the question. May I have your help please now?

Comment: So, you're struggling to find what have user chose on the final step?

Comment: on all steps actually , and when I get them all how do I send them?

Comment: One way is to get them in jquery (solution worked) , but how to send from jquery to php ?